# Exctract values from php array

Tags: php, arrays, extract

I have an array like this (this is actually a WordPress category list array):

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 4 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 6 ) )
```

Is there a way to exctract "term_id" values and assign it to $term variable with comma separated values?

in this case variable should be: $term = 4,6

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$term = implode(',', array_map(function($o) { return $o->term_id; }, $array));
```

Or:

```
$term = array();
foreach($array as $o) $term[] = $o->term_id;
$term = implode(',', $term);
```

In a function:

```
function getTerms($array) {
    $term = array();
    foreach($array as $o) $term[] = $o->term_id;
    return implode(',', $term);
}
```

Comment: You are a GENIUS ! I was spinning around for a good 3 hours and you solved it in 2 minutes :) THANKS !